# Not able to open particular website on my laptop

Tags: networking, dns

I am trying to open array151.com on my laptop. When I try to open this it shows ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT.

I tried nslookup and ping that too showing errors. Here is the output of nslookup and ping

```
C:\Users\Sunil Garg>nslookup array151.com
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  fe80::1caf:5e12:5cf5:2850

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    array151.com
Address:  67.227.164.146


C:\Users\Sunil Garg>ping array151.com

Pinging array151.com [67.227.164.146] with 32 bytes of data
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 67.227.164.146:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),
```

I tried flushing out dns server and disabling firewall. Nothing works.

Comment: Use tracert on the domain, and then contact your ISP, to tell them your unable to contact one of the hops

Comment: @Ramhound - I can see it from UK: maybe it has just come back on-line in the last few minutes; or maybe certain regions are locked out. (Response to your previous comment before it was replaced.)

Comment: i am able to acesss from all other devices.. from same network and from phone . but this is not working from my laptop

Comment: This may be a browser issue. Have you tried different browsers?

Comment: yes tried different browser and incognito windows, cleared cache...

Answer (score 0):

#### This is not working from my laptop

Try reinitialising the network states. Run the following commands in an elevated `cmd` shell:

- Reset WINSOCK entries to installation defaults:

  `netsh winsock reset catalog`
- Reset TCP/IP stack to installation defaults:

  `netsh int ip reset reset.log`
- Reset Firewall to installation defaults:

  `netsh advfirewall reset`
- Flush DNS resolver cache:

  `ipconfig /flushdns`
- Renew DNS client registration and refresh DHCP leases:

  `ipconfig /registerdns`
- Flush routing table (reboot required):

  `route /f`